# how to do alert dialog box activity

Tags: android

I have one button when I click the button it shows the alert dialog box with three options. i am click the first option do something like second and third option. how to do in android. i am very new android can you anyone please help me for this

**This is my code**

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"set", "option"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProgramInfoActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Share the Program");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {     
                if( set){

                }
                else if (option){

                }
                }});
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

Thanks
raj.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code...you can use it with small changes...just add another button and that it. My button Yes open another screen....

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface ad, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PronadjiKlopuActivity.this, TrenutnaLokacija.class);
                startActivity(i);               
            }
        });

        ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();

            }
        });
 ad.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use setMultiChoiceItems method.

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
               .setTitle( "Planets" )
               .setMultiChoiceItems( _options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler() )
               .setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler() )
               .create();
```

Following reference will help you:

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/android-multi-selection-dialogs/